# How to save the header api at global

Tags: python

I have 2 functions which taking header of same. Can i save at global so that i no need to call every time

```
def funct1():
    json_d = {"group_id": "uid"} 
    headers = {"account-id":"xxx","api-key":"xxx","Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.post("https://example.com/docs",headers=headers,json=json_d)

def funct2():
    json_d = {"group_id": "uid"} 
    headers = {"account-id":"xxx","api-key":"xxx","Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.post("https://example.com/docs",headers=headers,json=json_d)
```

Can I do

`headers = {"account-id":"xxx","api-key":"xxx","Content-Type": "application/json"}
 global headers`

Comment: what is the actual difference between the two functions?

Comment: Have you tried it…? Just define `headers` outside both functions, done. No need for “`global`” even.

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol changes are there in json_d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd recommend making a function for a default http call.

In this case only the json_d is different per function. Maybe this will also be the URL or other things, you can easy *move them up* to the initial functions and parameterize them in the `default_post()` function.

Using `**kwargs` you can make it more generic, for example if you want to pass a timeout you can call `default_post(..., timeout=3)` which is passed automatically to the `requests.post` function.

*Example*

```
def funct1():
    json_d_1 = {
        "group_id": "uid_1"
    } 
    default_post(json_d_1)

def funct2():
    json_d_2 = {
        "group_id": "uid_2"
    } 
    default_post(json_d_2)

def default_post(json_d, ..., **kwargs):
    headers = {"account-id":"xxx","api-key":"xxx","Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.post(
        "https://example.com/docs",
        headers=headers,
        json=json_d,
        **kwargs
    )
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a function that will return the headers dictionary in order to "protect" it from changes:

```
def get_headers():
    return {"account-id":"xxx","api-key":"xxx","Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

In this case at every call to the *get_headers* function new dictionary will be created so if you change it (the headers dictionary) in one function it does not effect the other function (unless what is that you are trying to achieve).

Comment: can I do like this  `  response = requests.post("https://example.com/docs",headers=get_headers(),json=json_d)`

Comment: The function will return a dictionary, so it should behave the same as sending global or function variable.
Try it.